# Uniform convergence of that series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Is $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n} {1+nx} $$ uniformly convergent on $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$? I tried using the M-test but it wasn't successful, I don't think I can use it for this series.  Not sure how I could do it.  Thank you.

Comment: Please do not blank the question after it's already been answered.

Comment: I'd like to generalize the question to any positive d instead of 1/2, actually.

Comment: For each $d > 0$ and interval $[d, 1]$, the series is uniformly convergent by pretty much the same process as in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After noticing that the series is alternating, we have the control

$$\left|\sum_{n = N}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1 + nx}\right| \le \left|\frac{(-1)^N}{1 + Nx}\right| = \frac{1}{1 + Nx} \le \frac{1}{1 + N/2}$$

for all $x$ in the relevant range. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Not sure I understand the first step.

Comment: The remainder in an alternating series can be estimated by the current term.

Answer (score 0):

The series is uniformly convergent on any compact subset excluding $0$. This follows from Dirichlet's test.

The Dirichlet's test states that if $\sum f(x)$ has uniformly bounded partial sums and if $g_n(x)\to 0$ uniformly on some set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $\sum f_n(x)g_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $E$. This can be proved by summation by part.